# Obj-C Downpicker file not found, can simulate but can't ARCHIVE

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, archive

Initially my app belongs to a different Apple ID, I have transferred my app to another Apple ID.
I debugged a few problems with X-code and simulated and everything works fine.
Then I created a new provision profile and tried to archive the App to AppStore. This is when I got the following problem.

RootviewController.h and RegisterViewController.h cannot detect the UIDownpicker.h file

[image: Downpicker file not found]

[image: RegisterViewController]
[image: RootViewController]

But the error doesn't show here. UIDownpicker.h file is detected at ProfileEdit.h No error here, I don't get it.

[image: ProfileEdit.h]

I have install UIDownpicker POD. But the error still exists.

[image: POD Installed]

The interface builder, the RootViewController and RegisterViewController is out of the Tab Bar Controller. Is it the cause?

[image: Interface Builder]

To all the gurus out there, please help me.

After removing **Use Framework** and did a pod install

**My Pod file**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Share Fitness' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic #frameworks

pod "DownPicker"
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
```

end

I got the following error log, please help

[image: linker problem]

[image: error]

### Target Name

[image: error1]

### Pod Install

[image: Pod Install]

Comment: Maybe the issue is not the specific pod, but the integration with your release configuration. Can you check `Preferences > General > Continue building after errors` and report back with your error logs? (Btw did you try to `pod install`? I see that you got a couple of xcconfig files that are missing as well)

Comment: @Alladinian please look at my above error log and let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that your target name is `Share Fitness` and not `SFITNESS`? Click on the project icon, what is listed in the `targets` list?

Comment: @Alladinian to the best of my knowledge the targets should be Share Fitness, please the attached pic.

Comment: @Alladinian, this is an extension to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616194/obj-c-xcode10-1-cannot-archive-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to please check it out

Comment: have you tried remove the derived data?

Comment: Tried but not working, I have re-do my app from last save. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be a Captain Obvious but have you tried Clean build, delete Derrived Data?
and then pod deintegrate && pod install[image]

Also check the location of your derrived data here

Comment: Tried not working, I have re-do the app from last saved, thanks.

Comment: how did you do archive? have you chose Generic ios device? because i see on your screenshots iPhone is chosen

Comment: Yes I did choose Generic, apparently my project was corrupted not sure where and I have to redo from backup.